# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar una pagina con Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Quiero redireccionar una página desde otra, es decir que cuando habrá una ventana ejemplo: ventana1 esta debe hacer una validación donde si hay datos pendientes que faltan por ser aprobados ejemplo ventana2 quiero que cuando yo haga clic en la ventana1 se redireccione automáticamente a la ventana

```
public function vista(){
    $this->load->view('carpeta/ventana2');
}
```

Este sería el controlador de php que carga la vista.

---

Y este sería el js que debe hacer la llamada para cargar la vista

```js
function ventana2(){
  $.post(
        'controlador/listar',
        function (data) {
            var tabla = JSON.parse(data)
            if (tabla.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
          url: 'controlador/vista',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(){
            swal("Usted tiene constancias de Bienes y servicios pendientes")
          }
        })
                
            }
        }
    )
}

ventana2();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"",        
    method: "POST",  
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function( ){  
    }             
});
```

yo uso ese  codigo para redireccionar  aotra pagina en ajax

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolver el problema del porqué no redireccionaba.
Como se trababa de un proyecto en la cual la url no cambiaba, codigos como `window.location.href = data.redirect` (en el ajax del js) no iba a funcionar en lo absoluto debido a que como antes dicho la url no cambiaba en nada, solo debía cambiar la vista, para entender un poco mejor es como cambiar un layout. además debía hacer que el controlador que cargaba la vista tuviera los datos del usuario o nada mas su id porque en la vista donde se debía redireccionar esta listaba una tabla donde traía los datos que tiene ese usuario en la bd

controlador en php

```
public function vista(){
   $id = $this->session->userdata('s_idUsuario');
   $param['id'] = $id;
   $this->load->view('carpeta/ventana2');}
```

---

codigo js

```js
function ventana2(){
  $.post(
        'controlador/listar',
        function (data) {
            var tabla = JSON.parse(data)
            if (tabla.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
          url: 'controlador/vista',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            $("#ventana2").html(data)
            swal("Usted tiene constancias de Bienes y servicios pendientes")
          }
        })
                
            }
        }
    )
}

ventana2();
```